# In Eclipse IDE, when I run any Program popup window says Error in Workspace and Error in program but running program operation successfully

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, sum

Problem occurs when I calculate large operation which run on console window over 3 minutes or more.

For example, calculating the sum of **n** natural numbers (where **n** is number entered by a user to calculate sum from 0 to **n**). In this it is a problem a user enters 10000000. The console window starts calculate sum according to code which takes some time and the process is running which you can see in console window. If you close the console by clicking the X button.

Now, run same program againt then console window will not open. However, if I hover over the <kbd>Run</kbd> button in Eclipse IDE I see the message:

> "Run( classname (running already))"

Instead of

> "Run [program name here]".

If you again run this program/code you get same thing. Next, I go to <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Show View</kbd> -> <kbd>Console</kbd>. Afterwards the Console window is open and you can entered any number for sum and you get output in console. But when doing this you have to open Console window manually after running your code which is not convenient to do repeatedly. You can also pin the Console window but sometimes it covers desktop space.

An error popup generally shows up when we run a program in Eclipse but in this case the popup shows with error but program continues running after manually opening the Console window (using <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Show View</kbd> -> <kbd>Console</kbd>). The popup has a heading "[Error in Workspace]" and under it "[Error in Program]".

Comment: This is rather hard to follow. To stop a program running click the Red box (Terminate) at the top right of the console view - do not click the Console close button, that does not stop the program.

Comment: Minimize the _Console_ view, when it covers to much space instead of closing it: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-39g.htm

Comment: @greg-449 , I clicked on red box also but same problem happens for other program also.how to stop this manually or any settings like.

Comment: Could you please explain why you close the view and then open it again instead of just minimize it? Are you aware of the _Show Console When Standard Out Changes_ toggle button? When pressed, the _Console_ view will be automatically shown as soon something is printed into the _Console_ view.

Comment: @howlger ,okk this issue happen only with one program which I mentioned in description of question.so if you read full you find out where problem occurs .I faced " console window not open " problem only with one program (mentioned in description of question) . With other program when I run , console window is open as regular it happens. So now understand what I'm trying to explain there. NOTE: when I go to "display selected console" there is only same program display which create this problem.

Comment: @MrException That is not an answer to either of my two questions. Please don't steal my time with _"if you read full"_ phrases.

Comment: @howgler ,sorry if I take your important time but I face this issue still. I'm confused what to do.(your Ques..Could you please explain why you close the view and then open it again instead of just minimize it?) Answer. From starting to now I am close the console view after running program and console is open.its like my habbit.(2ques..Are you aware of the Show Console When Standard Out Changes toggle button?) Ans..yes I put toggle on. Please help me because I am explained all as much as I understand ,so if point I missed please tell me your advice is appreciatiable.